# How to compile a C program for Genymotion (Android x86)

Tags: android, c, gcc, android-ndk, genymotion

I'm trying to build a simple HelloWorld application and run it on Genymotion.
My building system is Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. I have Android SDK(r22.6.2) and NDK(r9d) installed.

First Attempt: Build using the prebuilt NDK ARM toolchain

```
TOOLCHAIN = $NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8
$TOOLCHAIN/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=$PLATFORM hello.c -o hello
adb push hello /sdcard/
./hello
```

I get an error

```
/system/bin/sh: ./Hello: not executable: magic 7F45
```

After doing some research, I quickly realize Genymotion has **x86** arch instead of **ARM**

Second Attempt: Build using x86 Standalone ToolChain

1. Make x86 standlone toolchain first

   ```
   cd $NDK/build/tools
   ./make-standalone-toolchain.sh --arch=x86 --platform=android-19 --install-dir=/tmp/android-toolchain --ndk-dir=../../. --system=linux-x86_64
   ```
2. Build Hello using the toolchain

   ```
   cd tmp/android-toolchain/bin
   ./i686-linux-android-gcc -o Hello -c hello.c
   ```
3. Run Hello on Genymotion

   ```
   adb push hello /data/local/tmp
   adb shell
   cd /data/local/tmp
   ./hello
   /system/bin/sh: ./Hello: not executable: magic 7F45
   ```

Ran `uname -a` on the genymotion machine.
[image: Android System Name]
Ran `file Hello` on the executable
[image: Hello File info]

So it should be a match.

Still getting the same error. Would really appreciate it if someone could shed some light.

**Edit 1:** Tried running the executable in /data/local/tmp instead of /sdcard/. Still gives the same error.

**Edit 2:** Ran `uname` on genymotion system and `file` on the executable to see if they match.

Comment: I believe there is a confusion: you push `hello` to `/sdcard`, but run `Hello` from `/` (root directory). At any rate, Android mounts the /sdcard and other external storage as non-executable, for security reasons. Therefore, if you want to push and run your executable, use some other directory. `/data/local/tmp` is usually a good choice.

Comment: I just tried running the executable in /data/local/tmp. Still gives me the same error

Comment: Did you run `chmod 700 /data/local/tmp/hello`?

Comment: Yup, already gave the file permission to be executable.

Comment: Have you tried using [agcc](http://plausible.org/andy/agcc) script?

Comment: I think the agcc script is targeted towards ARM architecture, but not x86?

Comment: Have you tried plain GCC?

Comment: when your module is buid call the 'file' command on it, you shoud see it is x86 otherwise it means that you build has something wrong....

Comment: See my edit 2. I checked the file and it seems that the executable matches the system.

Comment: And yes i tried plain GCC. It will build a x86_64 version since my system is linux 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

If plain GCC doesn't get your job done, you'll have to take the harder route.

You need a cross-toolchain; I suggest generating a Canadian cross toolchain using Crosstool~ng; you can use NDK's standalone toolchain as a starting point.